# Разница между указателем на массив и указателем на двумерный массив

Tags: указатели

Не очень могу понять, для чего нужны указатели на массив, состоящего из N элементов.
Массив указателей - это понятно. У Вас просто кучка указателей одинакового типа.
Указатель на двумерный массив - это указатель, с помощью которого можно получить доступ к элементам, являющимися составными частями массива, который в свою очередь лежит в всеобъемлющем массиве (аналогия с вложенными отрезками в математическом анализе).
А вот указатель на массив из N элементов это как понять? Буквально? Это разве не указатель на двумерный массив, с помощью которого можно получить доступ к массивам, вложенным в огромный массив, а не к элементам меньших массивов? 
Объясните, пожалуйста. Извините, если вопрос кажется тупым

Comment: Вы как-то сложно мыслите. Указатель - это число, адрес памяти. Указатель на массив - это адрес, по которому находится нулевой элемент массива.

Comment: Я просто до этого изучал математику, поэтому вложенные отрезки почему-то сразу пришли на ум, хотя точнее это классы эквивалентности скорее (массиы в массиве) на декартовом произведении множеств.

Answer (score 1):

Пример на ЯП С++

Указатели и массивы тесно связаны. Обычно компилятор преобразует массив в указатели. С помощью указателей можно манипулировать элементами массива, как и с помощью индексов.

Имя массива по сути является адресом его первого элемента. Соответственно через операцию разыменования мы можем получить значение по этому адресу:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::cout << "a[0] = " << *a << std::endl;    // a[0] = 1
```

Имя массива всегда хранит адрес самого первого элемента. И нередко для перемещения по элементам массива используются отдельные указатели.

```
int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *ptr = a;
int a2 = *(ptr+2);
std::cout <<  "value: " << a2 << std::endl;  // value: 3
```

Здесь указатель ptr изначально указывает на первый элемент массива. Увеличив указатель на 2, мы пропустим 2 элемента в массиве и перейдем к элементу a[2]

Так как указатель хранит адрес, то мы можем продолжать цикл, пока адрес в указателе не станет равным адресу последнего элемента.

Как обстоят дела с многомерным (в вашем случае двумерным) массивом: Адресом первого элемента будет выражение a[0]. Соответственно указатель указывает на этот элемент. С каждой итерацией указатель увеличивается на единицу, пока его значение не станет равным адресу последнего элемента, который хранится в указателе end.

Comment: Спасибо, большое!